# NSManagedObject properties set to nil return 0

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I know this is probably by design but I thought I'd check with the community first.

How come when I have an NSManagedObject that's new, its NSNumber properties return 0? I want them to be nil til they've been set.

Comment: `nil` **is** 0. So is `NULL`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you just forget to uncheck the `default` value option?
The NSManagedObject will return nil for that attribute if `default` is unchecked and the attribute was never set. At least that's what happens in my app.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that would be the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a **NSNumber** behavior. Once it is created but not assigned a value, it is set to 0.

Hope that helps

Comment: I still think that unset property values are `nil`. Since any message sent to `nil` returns `nil`, `[nil intValue] == 0`.

Comment: Thanks, mbh. It helps. Just kinda bites. How would you check to see if an NSNumber attribute was set or not? Is there a way? Should I make my default value -1 or something fancy like that?

Comment: Check first if the property is `nil` before you get `intValue`.

Comment: I'm not looking for the intValue. The problem is that if I ever check that it's nil it comes back as 0 not nil.